# Handling php echo data via HttpURLConnection on Android

Tags: java, php, android, http

I am trying to login a user on an android app via this activity:

```
    public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnKeyListener{


        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick( View v ) {
                userLogin();
            }
        });


    }


    private void userLogin() {
        String userName = edtUsername.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = edtPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        String method = "login";

        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,userName,password);


        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainMenuActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}
```

using this BackgroundTask:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context ctx;
    HttpURLConnection conn;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params ) {

        String method = params[0];
        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String firstName = params[1];
            String lastName = params[2];
            String userName = params[3];
            String email = params[4];
            String pass = params[5];

            Log.i("inBackgground", firstName + " " + lastName + " " + userName + " " + email);

            try {
                URL url = new URL(URLs.URL_REGISTER);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("first", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(firstName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("last", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(lastName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("uid", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("pwd", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(pass, "UTF-8");

                Log.i("inbackgroundFURTHER", data);


                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                inputStream.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

        }


        if (method.equals("login")) {
            String jsonString;

            String userName = params[1];
            String password = params[2];

            try {
                URL url = new URL(URLs.URL_LOGIN);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setDoInput(true);

                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                String data = URLEncoder.encode("uid", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("pwd", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&";


                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    Log.i("resultobj: ", result.toString());
                    return(result.toString());


                }else{
                    Log.i("response code: ", Integer.toString(response_code));
                    return("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return "i don't know what to return here";
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute( String result ) {

        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate( Void... values ) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

The used php script looks like this:

```
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

$response = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck < 1) {
    exit();
} else {
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        //De-hashing the password
        $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
        if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
            exit();
        } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {

            $user = array();
            $user["user_id"] = $row[0];
            $user["user_first"] = $row[1];
            $user["user_last"] = $row[2];
            $user["user_email"] = $row[3];
            $user["user_uid"] = $row[4];

            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"] = array();

            array_push($response["user"], $user)

            echo json_encode($response);
            exit();
        }
        exit();


    }
}
```

At the moment I am trying just to display a result before I move to the next step using sharedprefs and a user object in order to keep the user logged in and do something with its user information.

The problem is, that I do not get any results with HTTP error code 500.

What am I doing wrong?

If I need to provide more information of any kind, please tell me!

Comment: Are you saying that you are getting an HTTP error code 500?

Comment: what do your server logs say about a '500' , any messages in the http or php logs?

Comment: There are few things you might want to consider in coding your app: 1) You are calling the `BackgroundTask` and then immediately afterwards you are starting the `MainMenuActivity` without even knowing whether the login was successful. `AsyncTask` is asynchronous so you should wait for the response before moving on. You could do this with a listener or ...What I would suggest: recode the `HttpURLConnection` portion of your code to make it more universal and make a `AsyncTask` in your  `LoginActivity` and use the `onPostExecute()` method to start the new `Activity` when login data is correct.

Comment: 2) You should design your php so that you get a response regardless of whether the query or the parameters are correct. 3) you php code is not safe from SQL injection--I recommend you use PDO with `bindParam`.

Comment: Hey Barns,
i just implemented a user login check by using Shared preferences and a user object in order to check if the user is logged in and only then proceed to the next activity.

Additionally why is my php script vulnerably to SQL injection if I use mysqli_real_escape_string?

Shouldn't this php method prevent SQL injections?

Comment: There is sufficient info on the web to show how  `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not reliable protection against SQLinjection. The code you posted does leave you open to attack--even with `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: But lets get back to the `Shared preferences` login design you are using. The code you posted does not demonstrate your described methodology. Your code triggers the `AsyncTask` and immediately calls `startActivity` to "MainMenuActivity"--sounds like access to me. Lets say your `AsyncTask` takes a while to execute how do you resolve this in the next `Activity` maybe it calls up an old pref from the last login session? In my opinion, too many conditionals to check. Its better to just refuse access to critical activities based on the response not the stored pref.

Comment: Hey,
I will use bind_param functions for my php script, I am very new to this topic and thankful for your help!
For login I check first if there is some shared pref, if so -> start the main menu.
If not the user has to pass in the login info which is checked by the php script and sent back as a json format to create an user object and therewith some shared prefs in order to get user details whenever the app needs them.

The Asynctask logs the user in and starts the mainmenuactivy.

Only if the json has some specific information in it, the shared prefs are created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the php script a bit and now it works just fine, thank you all!

```
  <?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

$response = array();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid';";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($resultCheck < 1) {
    echo 'error resultCheck < 1';
    exit();
} else {
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        //De-hashing the password
        $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
        if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
         echo 'error hashedPwdCheck == false';
         exit();
        } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {

            $user = array();
            $user["user_id"] = $row[0];
            $user["user_first"] = $row[1];
            $user["user_last"] = $row[2];
            $user["user_email"] = $row[3];
            $user["user_uid"] = $row[4];
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["user"] = array();


            array_push($response["user"], $user);


            echo json_encode($user);
            exit();
        }
       echo 'final exit';
       exit();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your PHP script, try to replace it with this code to handle the error.

```
  <?php
    include 'dbh.inc.php';

    $uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
    $pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

    $response = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid='$uid' OR user_email='$uid';";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($resultCheck < 1) {
        echo 'error resultCheck < 1';
        exit();
    } else {
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            //De-hashing the password
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
             echo 'error hashedPwdCheck == false';
             exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {

                $user = array();
                $user["user_id"] = $row[0];
                $user["user_first"] = $row[1];
                $user["user_last"] = $row[2];
                $user["user_email"] = $row[3];
                $user["user_uid"] = $row[4];

                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["user"] = array();

                array_push($response["user"], $user)

                echo json_encode($response);
                exit();
            }
           echo 'final exit';
           exit();


        }
    }
```

Comment: as well, you can test the PHP script using POSTMAN to make sure it's work as you expected. then test the android code